# But seriously, how does one go about creating an internet shortcut within a folder in Ubuntu LTS 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys

Does anyone out there know how to create an internet shortcut within a folder? I don't mean to be picky here but the shortcut should have these properties:

1. It has to work.
2. It has to be searchable within the dash and the icon has to show up with it.
3. That's pretty much it.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Google Chrome version 29.0.1547.65.

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2):

In Nautilus go to:

File > Connect to Server...

And connect to wherever you wish to. Once connected go to:

Bookmarks > Add Bookmark

A new bookmark will show up in the bottom of the bookmark list shown in the left pane by Nautilus. If you wish to change the name of the new bookmark right click on it an choose "Rename...".

This bookmark will always be available in the left pane, accessible from whatever folder you are in.

Comment: Is it searchable and can I hide the bookmarks in the left pane?